# How to find a constant of a PDF if integral diverges

Tags: probability, integration

So I'm given a probability density function:

***p(x) = $\frac{ke^{\frac{x}{a}}}{a}$*** when ***0 < x < $\infty$***

Find the value of ***k***.

I assume I can solve this by solving the equation:

***$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ke^{\frac{x}{a}}}{a} dx = 1$$***.

However when I solve it find out the integral diverges into infinity.

Even when I use an integral calculator online it gives me the same answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider what values of $a$ would cause the integral to converge. Also please share what antiderivative you arrived at; your error might be there.